# sending the request to physical process in Castalia?

Tags: omnet++

when sensor manager sends the request to physical process using gate index for sensor device :

send(requestMsg, "toNodeContainerModule", corrPhyProcess[sensorIndex]);

will the physical process receive the request message regardless of the distance with node? or whether the physical process receives the msg or not will depend on the distance?

The physical process has a fixed value and it never changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physical process will always get the message from any node.

Figure 1 of the Castalia manual shows that a physical process module is connected to all the nodes. So when a node sends an OMNeT message to that module, it will be received.

Of course, what will the physical process do with the message and what value it will return, it depends on the specific physical process you implement.

Comment: and when the physical process replies back, does the node receives the reply regardless of the distance?

Comment: If a phy process replies back, of course the node will receive the message. We are talking about OMNeT messages here. Are you implying that OMNeT might not work correctly?

Comment: I am talking about the communication between a node and physical process. I am trying to figure out the distance factor affecting the communication. and I understand now that distance doesn't affect the communication because the modules are linked.

Comment: The communication between modules is not affected. Of course the value that the phy process returns can be affected by distance or whatever parameter the phyprocess chooses to.